# ConstraintLayout view binding migration from Kotlin synthetics

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I have an existing view that extends from `ConstraintLayout` which looks something like this:

```kotlin
class LandingTemplate: ConstraintLayout {

  init {
    inflate(context, R.layout.landing_template, this)
    
    // Currently this 'recyclerView' is a kotlin synthetic
    recyclerView.run {
      // this sets up the recycler view
    }
}
```

I'm familiar with view binding with activities and fragments, but I can't find any documentation around the extends layout case.
My question is, what do I replace that initial `inflate` call with here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a context available from your constructor and your XML layout's top level tag is `<merge>`. You can use your binding class's `inflate` to create and add the child layout.

And since this can all be set up in the constructor, you don't need `lateinit var` like in the Activity/Fragment examples, and can just use `val` instead.

```
class LandingTemplate(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

    private val binding = LandingTemplateBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this)

    init {
        binding.recyclerView.run {
            // this sets up the recycler view
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the top level is a `<merge>`, this worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you  can get layout inflater like below

```
 val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

 val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.landing_temple,this,true)
```

and you must have valid view construct too

```
 LandingTemple(Context) // for creating view programmatically

 LandingTemple(Context,AttrributeSet) // to inflate view from xml , and 
 //the constructor context is one that you use to call `getSystemService
```

for more information [check](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html)